# Propagator for phase space with Lagrangian boundary conditions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, propagator

I am dealing with an generalized action functional of the form

$$\tilde{S}(\gamma) = \int_0^T\left(p\dot{q} - H(p,q)\right)dt+f_1(q(0))-f_2(q(T)) = S(\gamma) + f_1 - f_2$$

where $f_1$ and $f_2$ define Lagrangian submanifolds that dictate the boundary conditions. I would like to understand how to compute the propagator for the free particle, $H(p,q) = \frac{1}{2m}p^2$. Naively, the path integral is,

$$K(T,x,x') = \int_\gamma \mathcal{D}\gamma \; e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}f_1}e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}f_2}e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}S(\gamma)}$$

I believe I should be able to calculate this via knowledge of the propagator for the usual free particle (that is without the generalized boundary conditions),

$$K_{free}(T,x,x') = \sqrt{\frac{m}{2\pi i \hbar T}}e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{m(x'-x)^2}{2T}}$$

along with some appropriate change of coordinates and Fourier transform. I haven't been able to find a source that guides me through the process or does an example, though I have found paper that discuss the topic in some amount, such as [this paper by Dedushenko](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.04274.pdf) and [this paper by Chmielowiec and Kijowski](http://www.cft.edu.pl/~kijowski/Odbitki-prac/gq_v16.pdf), where the first one sets up the appropriate path integral (but doesn't solve it) and the second one gives tools for solving something similar but I can't seem to relate it to what I have.

Any guidance or help on how to compute this propagator would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which pages/equations in the 2 links discuss the topic?

Comment: I believe the practice they outline in section 2 using the fractional Fourier transform is what I can use...but I haven't been able to understand their discussion on geometric quantization that generalizes it.

Comment: Can you be more specific?